# GraphQL - Error while trying to upload files with apolloUploadExpress

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

how are you?
I am trying to configure my graphql server to allow sending files along with my mutation.
I've tried it in several ways, now I'm trying with **apolloUploadExpress**, and until then with no success.
The initialization of my server looks like this:

```
const app = express();
app.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), 
apolloUploadExpress({
uploadDir: '/home/xxx/projects/xx/upload/'
 }),
graphqlExpress(req => {
return {
    context: {
        req
    },
    graphiql: true,
    schema,
    rootValue: root
};
}));
```

My curl looks like this:

```
curl -X POST   http://localhost:5000/graphql     -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'   -H 'postman-token: 7c5230d1-1605-6559-7609-ab373934831e'   -F 'query={"query":"mutation{\n  setImage(input:{clientMutationId:\"123\", id:\"123\", part:\"asda\"}){\n    clientMutationId\n  }\n}","variables":null}'   -F file=@/home/xxxxx/Pictures/cat.jpg
```

When I do the curl I get error. And in the graphql console it appears:

> undefined:1 
>   undefined ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
>       at Object.parse

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had similar problem. Make sure that you include

Upload: GraphQLUpload in your resolver

See https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-server#upload-scalar